# make image draggable javavascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i would like to know how i can make images draggable i have accomplished resizable but not draggable for some reason the code is not working i tried dropable but its not working either what can i do?

```js
<script>
    // External added
    jQuery(download).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper").hide();
        jQuery(".out-put-img1").hide();
        jQuery("#imajes45").change(function () {
            var selected = jQuery('#imajes45').val();
            if (selected == "new-upload") {
                jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper").show();
            } else {
                jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper").hide();
            }
        });

        //File
        function readURL(input) {

            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    jQuery(".out-put-img1").show();
                    $('#output1').attr('src', e.target.result);
//                   / $('.append-img').append('src', e.target.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
        jQuery("#upload-img1").change(function () {
            readURL(this);
   
 $('#dragbal').droppable();
$('#output1').resizable();
 

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Make sure you're linked to the relevant jQuery library.  https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: I tried that  but it's not working

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for any errors?

Comment: i will check ill let you know

Comment: i dont get any errors

Comment: Possible for you to create a jsfiddle please? I will see if I can get it working for you. https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: yes i will create one

Comment: here is my https://jsfiddle.net/2taya76y/2/

Comment: @NewToJS  sorry for bothering you will it be possible to make it work?